# Join query returns duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, join, inner-join

### purchase_request_master

```
prm_voucher_no| project_id| status_id|  request_date                        
17                 46           3      11-6-2016 0:00                       
18                 46           3      20-6-2016 0:00                       
19                 46           3      216-2016 0:00
```

### purchase_request_details

```
prm_voucher_no| item_id|    request_quantity                            
17                80         50                         
17                81         100                            
18                80         75                         
19                83         10                         
19                81         35                         
19                82         120
```

### purchase_order_master

```
pom_voucher_no| prm_request_id  |supplier_id                            
16                  17              14                          
17                  18              14                          
18                  19              15
```

### purchase_order_details

```
pom_voucher_no| approved_quantity|  rate                            
16                     50           1000                            
16                     100          1500                            
17                     75           150                         
18                     10           2500                            
18                     35           3000                            
18                     120          1700
```

when I run the below query it gives 14 rows(duplicate row returning).expected out put row is 6.. Please refer below output tables..

```
select prm.prm_voucher_no,prm.project_id,prm.status_id,prd.requested_quantity,prd.item_id,pom.pom_voucher_no,pom.supplier_id,pod.rate,pod.approved_quantity 
from purchase_request_master prm
left join purchase_request_details prd on prd.prm_voucher_no=prm.prm_voucher_no
left join purchase_order_master pom on prm.prm_voucher_no=pom.request_id
left join purchase_order_details pod on pom.pom_voucher_no=pod.pom_voucher_no
where prm.project_id=46 and ( EXTRACT(MONTH FROM prm.request_Date)=6) and (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM prm.request_Date)=2016) 
group by prm.voucher_no,prm.project_id,prm.status_id,prd.requested_quantity,prd.item_id,pom.voucher_no,pom.supplier_id,pod.rate,pod.approved_quantity 
order by prm.voucher_no
```

i tried inner join,distinct,distinct least,group by,temporary table,with clause all these method.. but no use every this gives duplicate row

How to solve this problem..

### OUTPUT

```
prm_voucher_no| project_id| status_id|item_id|request_quantity |pom_voucher_no| supplier_id|approved_quantity |  rate   
   17             46           3         80       50                 16               14       100               1000   
   17             46           3         81       100                16               14       75                1500   
   17             46           3         80        75                16               15       10                150    
   17             46           3         81        10                16               14       35                10 
   18             46           3         81        35                17               14       120               35 
   19             46           3         80        120               18               15       50                120    
   19             46           3         81        50                18               14       100               1000   
   19             46           3         82        100               18               14       75                1500   
   19             46           3         80        75                18               15       10                150    
   19             46           3         81        10                18               14       35                10 
   19             46           3         82        35                18               14       120               35 
   19             46           3         80        120               18               15       35                120    
   19             46           3         81        35                18               14       50                1500   
   19             46           3         82        50                18               15       100               1700
```

### EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
prm_voucher_no| project_id| status_id|  item_id|    request_quantity|   pom_voucher_no| supplier_id|approved_quantity|  rate    
    17             46          3          80             50                  16             14           100            1000    
    17             46          3          81             100                 16             14           75             1500    
    18             46          3          81             35                  17             14           120              35    
    19             46          3          80             120                 18             15           50              120    
    19             46          3          81             50                 18              14          100             1000    
    19             46          3          82             100                 18             14          75              1500
```

Comment: Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: this because you have same voucher number multiple times in `purchase_request_details` and `purchase_order_details`

Comment: you are getting what you asked for, so we can't really help you unless you explain what you wanted.
in the expected output you wrote for prm_voucher_no 17 you have 2 item_id. but in what you got you have 4 item_id's. so that's why you are getting twice as many rows.

Comment: i want to join these four table. 
from first table (**purchase_request_master**)
**prm_voucher_no, project_id, status_id**
second table (**purchase_request_details**)
**item_id,requested_quantity**
third table(**purchase_order_master**)
**pom_voucher_no,supplier_id**
fourth table(**purchase_order_details**)
**approved_quantity,rate**

conditions 

**project_id=46
and ( EXTRACT(MONTH FROM request_Date)=6) and (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM request_Date)=2016) **

Comment: well from what I can tell you are getting what you wanted. for each row that has different values like item_id, but the same prm_voucher_no you will get a duplicated row, one for each item_id. so the problem is in what you are expecting and not in what you are getting.
I would suggest removing the "where" and "group by" so you will see all the results, then adding each requirement 1 at a time and seeing where duplicated rows you expect to be removed are not being removed, then comparing them and seeing where the difference is.
Each difference between rows will create another row...

Comment: i cant remove where condition.. i need to check condition. 
above details are  just example data. and i am not getting what i want. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in your data model itself.  Ideally, you would have a `line_number` field in both of your "detail" tables, and this would be used in the join:

```
create table purchase_request_details (
    prm_voucher_no integer,
    prm_voucher_line integer,    // Add this
    item_id integer,
    request_quantity
)

create table purchase_order_details (
    pom_voucher_no integer,
    pom_voucher_line integer,    // and this
    approved_quantity integer,
    rate integer
)
```

And then this query would give you the results you seek:

```
select
  prm.prm_voucher_no,prm.project_id,prm.status_id,prd.request_quantity,
  prd.item_id,pom.pom_voucher_no,pom.supplier_id,pod.rate,pod.approved_quantity 
from
  purchase_request_master prm
  left join purchase_request_details prd on 
    prd.prm_voucher_no=prm.prm_voucher_no
  left join purchase_order_master pom on 
    prm.prm_voucher_no=pom.prm_request_id
  left join purchase_order_details pod on 
    pom.pom_voucher_no=pod.pom_voucher_no and
    prd.prm_voucher_line = pod.pom_voucher_line   // This is the key
where
  prm.project_id=46 and
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM prm.request_Date) = 6 and
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM prm.request_Date) = 2016
order by prm.prm_voucher_no
```

If you have no ability to control the data model, then I think the best you can do is artificially add a line number.  I don't recommend this at all, as you are presupposing a lot of things, most notably that the order of records in the one table automatically correlates to the order of records in the other -- and I'm betting that's far from a guarantee.

Adding a line number would be done using the row_number() analytic, and PostgreSQL has that but MySQL does not...  you have both tags in your question.  Which DBMS are you using?

If you can't add line numbers, can you add item_id to your `purchase_order_details` table?  This would likely handle your issue, unless you can have the same item on multiple lines within a purchase request/order.

In the data you have above, a join on the requested quantity (`prd.request_quantity = pod.approved_quantity`) fixes your issue, but I am highly confident that this would burn you when you started running it against real data.

Comment: problem solved.. prd.item_id=pod.item_id joined these filed also.. tq @Hambone